# RSpec: controller => action => outcome => context specification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, specifications

A really quick question on RSpec - I'd like have the following hierarchy of specifications:

- Controller - one per file, for example, `SearchController`
- Action - multiple actions per controller, each specified separately, for example, `search` or `suggest`
- Outcome - groups by the meaning of results received from the controller - i.e. if we're specifying `search`, then I'd like to group test cases by search results returned implied by the query, i.e. "search of articles", "search of users", "search of products"
- Context - same outcome can be reached within a couple of different contexts - i.e. in search controller example, that is "searching for articles" using various search phrases

For English specification dump, for the search controller example, I'd like to construct something like the following phrasing:

- SearchController

  - suggest

    - returns articles

      - by article text
      - by article header
    - returns users

      - by user name
      - by user age

Currently my code looks like that:

```
RSpec.describe SearchController do
  describe 'suggest' do
    it 'returns articles by article text' do
      get :suggest, text: 'some text'
      expect(response.body).to ...
    end
    it 'returns articles by article header' do
      ...
    end
    it 'returns users by user name' do
      ...
    end
    it 'returns users by user age' do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

It kind of works, but is there any way to improve it by introducing next level grouping and semantic stuff like `context`, `it` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different structure that should be easier to map to rspec syntax:

- SearchController

  - suggest

    - articles

      - finds by text
      - finds by header
    - users

      - finds by user name
      - finds by age

Spec might look like this:

```
describe SearchController do
  describe 'suggest' do
    context 'articles' do
      it 'finds by name' do
        ...
      end
      it 'finds by text' do
        ...
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you demonstrate which RSpec clauses should be used on which level exactly in this approach?

Comment: describe is an alias of context so it doesn't really matter which one you use.

Comment: Looks like it's a solution :) Is it considered a bad style to factor out "finds" (or "returns" - i.e. a description of action) as I've done in my original proposal - thus it's not really compatible with `it`?

Comment: TBH not sure what is considered bad/good style here. My style would be to include a verb as I have done above, this just makes the tests read a little better IMO, but I guess this is pretty subjective.